# how can i upgrade ioncube in shared host

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a error after extract own website in new hosting,
Before webhosting supported from php 5.6 but new hosting not supported.
I'd approciate your help

```
/wp-content/themes/martfury/functions.php was encoded by the ionCube Encoder for PHP 5.6 and cannot run under PHP 7.1 or later. Please ask the provider of the script to provide a version encoded with the ionCube Encoder for PHP 7.1. in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Can you not just encode it with the correct version? Or install master (unencoded) version to the new site. You do have an unencoded Master version dont you?

Comment: https://docs.whmcs.com/PHP_7_Migration_Troubleshooting_Guide

Comment: I checked problem is from php version but I cant change php version to 5.6 in new webhosting (webhosting not supported)

Comment: If this is your own code and you want it protected on your own server, which is a good idea for config files and those with sensitive data at the very least, simply re-encode the source files to target PHP 7. If you have Encoder version 9 that predates PHP 7, upgrade it to 10. If the files are from a 3rd party, ask them for files built for PHP 7.